# How to use a User Input String obtained in one file, in another file

Tags: python, typescript, import, vscode-extensions

I am new to TypeScript and VS Code Extensions and I was wondering how I could use a user inputted string from one file, in another file. The input string is a path to an .isf file. Here is the situation: I have an extension that takes in user input (its basically the quickinput-sample from VS code). when a user selects ShowInputBox the following function runs:

```
/**
 * Shows an input box using window.showInputBox().
 */
export async function showInputBox() {
    const result = await window.showInputBox({
        value: 'abcdef',
        valueSelection: [2, 4],
        placeHolder: 'For example: fedcba. But not: 123',
        validateInput: text => {
            window.showInformationMessage(`Validating: ${text}`);
            return text === '123' ? 'Not 123!' : null;
        }
    });
    window.showInformationMessage(`Got: ${result}`);
}
```

what I would like to do is rather than display the path in a informationMessage, I want the input to be used in the following code from a separate file:

```
#print(sessionId)

    HIDDEN.openLogFiles(sessionId, ["C:\\FOLDER\\5G_ServingCell_Rsrp_Rsrq_Sinr_RSSI_B974_all.isf"])
```

so essentially, I want the result to take the place of this hardcoded file path.
Any information on where to start with this would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: If you want the input to be used in another TS file, you can simply return the value of result and call the function in another TS file by exporting the function (as you've done) and importing the file from the other file. If you want to write to another file without getting any output, you can use FS, and if you want to execute code in another file with value as a paramter, you can try using node.js exec command. If any of these seem like a solution for you, I can provide more insight on how they actually work

Comment: Yes please! I am going to be working on this over the weekend. I will reach out to you once I get a chance to look into your proposed solutions!